# Hystrix Dashboard with Spring Boot Deployed On PCF not showing Metrics

Tags: spring, cloud-foundry, spring-cloud, hystrix

I created a simple app using Spring boot and the spring cloud starter hystrix library.

In my build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
compile("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-hystrix-dashboard:1.0.0.RC2")
compile("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-hystrix:1.0.0.RC2")
}
```

I deployed one app as a hystrix dashboard using the above libraries and `@EnableHystrixDashboard`

I then deployed another app which was annotated with `@EnableHystrix`

I added a component that has a command that I invoke through a controller, just to test things out:

```
@HystrixCommand(fallbackMethod = "onFailedToSayHello")
public String sayHello(Map<String, String> parameters) {
    if (parameters.get("fail") != null && parameters.get("fail").equals("yes")) {
        throw new RuntimeException("I failed because you told me to");
    }
    return "Hello";
}

private String onFailedToSayHello(Map<String, String> parameters) {
    return "Bye";
}
```

The hystrix app runs fine. When I hit the URL I see the stream, the ouptut of which I put in a gist [here](https://gist.github.com/ruairitobrien/a4c783773bda13a25bc4).

I just see that repeating over and over.

My dashboard is up and running and when I enter the URL of my running hystrix sample app I get a loading screen:

[image: hystrix dashboard loading screen]

Then, when I check my hystrix app again I see this:

```
λ curl http://myappurl/hystrix.stream
{"timestamp":1423748238280,"status":503,"error":"Service      Unavailable","message":"MaxConcurrentConnections reached: 5","path":"/hystrix.stream"}
```

I am not sure where to go from here. I tried deploying the hystrix dashboard war instead of building it myself which I downloaded from [here](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=com/netflix/hystrix/hystrix-dashboard/1.4.0-RC6/hystrix-dashboard-1.4.0-RC6.war) but got the same result.

I also noticed some JavaScript error outputs in the browser console which I put [here](https://gist.github.com/ruairitobrien/bc3ab26453c81dfd45ec) in case they are any use.

And in the server logs I see this repeated over and over:

> 2015-02-15 20:03:55.324  INFO 9360 --- [nio-8080-exec-9]
>   ashboardConfiguration$ProxyStreamServlet :
>
> Proxy opening connection to: http://myappurl/hystrix.stream

I am now going to try and get [turbine](https://github.com/Netflix/Turbine) running and see if using that somehow magically fixes things. Thought I would post here too though on the off chance someone can spot an error on my part based on what I've done so far.

EDIT:
An important point I didn't mention is that I have both the app and the dashboard deployed on PCF. This seems to be important since this issue doesn't happen when I deploy locally. Still no idea what's causing it though.

Comment: By default only 5 connections are allowed to the hystrix stream.  Set `hystrix.stream.maxConcurrentConnections: 20`.  Can you try with 1.0.0.RC3 which just released a bit ago?  There are some fixes for the hystrix dashboard.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @spencergibb. I tried updating the app and the dashboard to 1.0.0.RC3 but got the same error. The I changed the max concurrent connections to 20 and got a similar error: {"timestamp":1424029687607,"status":503,"error":"Service Unavailable","message":"MaxConcurrentConnections reached: 20","path":"/hystrix.stream"}. Looks similar to this https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/issues/85 but I haven't found anything useful there as it seems to be an old issue with hystrix that was fixed a while back.

Comment: what do you have connecting to it that takes up 20 connections?

Comment: As far as i can tell it's the dashboard. When I point the dashboards to my app the error occurs and I see this repeated in the dashboard app logs: 'Proxy opening connection to: http://myappurl/hystrix.stream'. Then I can no longer access the stream and get that 503 error. When I close the dashboard the 503 stops and I can see the stream again. The stream looks OK. I see the right contentype - Content-Type:text/event-stream;charset=UTF-8. It's a bit of a strange one really. I'm baffled. I'll hopefully get time to look in to it over the next few days and will update here if I find anything.

Comment: a bug in the servlet was locking access when no data is present try upgrading to 1.4.0-rc.9 https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/commit/b975eb4ec04dd2df47411c9bbcad849e313826b4

Comment: @mestachs - thank you. Upgrading the the hystrix server version did actually sort out the problem of too many open connections it looks like. Still not getting any stats on the dashboard though. Seems to be an issue while running in cloud foundry though.

Comment: Sorry don't know much about cloud foundry. What about troubleshooting the different urls (browser js -> [proxy](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/blob/master/hystrix-dashboard/src/main/java/com/netflix/hystrix/dashboard/stream/ProxyStreamServlet.java) servlet in dashboard war -> stream servlet in turbine war (verify default cluster instances properties, can it reach the cluster nodes directly ?) -> each nodes hystrix.stream servlet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem goes away if you build hystrix-dashboard from the latest [source](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix), or use the most recently released [war](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.netflix.hystrix/hystrix-dashboard/1.4.3) (version 1.4.3 on 27th March at time of writing).

Answer (score 0):

Several things can probably lead to MaxConcurrentConnections, and one of them is no any metrics data generated by the application. The servlets (Hystrix.stream servlets) will keep looping to wait data, then it will consumes all the connections. There are very good discussion on the Hystrix github wiki. For example: 
[hystrix.stream holds connection open if no metrics #85](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/issues/85)